# Configuration change tracking system

Tags: java, linux, bash, deployment, configuration

Don't know this is the correct place to ask but, I need to know is there any way or any tools available to track/validate configuration file changes after deployment. I could not find any tool to achieve this. please help me,

Ex :

Original file:

```
a.b.c = 20
p.q.r = 30
```

Change

```
a.b.c = 30
```

After deployment, I need to validate that the above file is changed according to the instruction given above,

```
a.b.c = 30
p.q.r = 30
```

Comment: Both the lines in your configuration file have the same parameter `a.b.c` on the LHS of `=` sign. Is that intentional?

Comment: oh sorry ... I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your problem statement correctly. I think, this is what you want:

```
$ cat orig.conf
a.b.c = 20
p.q.r = 30

$ cat change
a.b.c = 30

$ cat modified.conf
a.b.c = 30
p.q.r = 30
```

If this is correct interpretation, you can use this:

```
$ awk -F' *= *' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a){$0=a[$1]}1' change orig.conf
a.b.c = 30
p.q.r = 30
```

If you also want to add any new entries from `change`, you can use this:

```
$ cat change
a.b.c = 30
d.e.f = 50

$ awk -F' *= *' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a){$0=a[$1]; delete a[$1];}1; END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' change orig.conf
a.b.c = 30
p.q.r = 30
d.e.f = 50
```

Comment: I think this is it. thank youuuu..

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.